# 400 Bad request for concurrent 10 sessions hitting REST API from Informatica

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, informatica

I have an Informatica integration workflow processing around 200 or 100 records each session for 10 sessions concurrently to REST API (Salesforce). It first authorizes using connected app details (client_id), client and gets token and use this token to post the data to the REST API. However, I get 400 bad request, authentication failure (means it may face error at authorization itself) when I run 10 sessions at a time. With single session it runs fine, so the issue is not with the code and 5 sessions run good but sometimes we receive timeout based commit point.

Is there any concurrent api requests limit that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a concurrent API limit for long-running REST requests in SF as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm).

Apart from this,  I hope you are reusing the access token returned from oauth until that token is invalid, Because authenticating it again and again may hit `Login Exceeded` limit if the load is huge.

Comment: It is better to quote the documentation using text since it is then searchable. The limits you have copied/pasted have a caveat immediately above them; this applies to long running requests only. Please update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Correct, its only for 20 seconds and above.

Comment: The integration service using 10 sessions always hits the login url for token and then in downstream uses this token along with body to post to end point URL. you mean this 10 concurrent hitting login URL is causing issue, but I came to know from SF person the concurrent limit is 25, so why we get error for 10 requests at a time.

Comment: if 10 request are sent at a time, assume it already reached 25 requests, the remaining requests will be in queue and gets failed?

Comment: All requests above the limit will fail. It wont get queued.